# Is it possible to us RxAndroiBle, autoconnect in foreground?

Tags: rxandroidble

I will try to post a question since I want to use RxAndroidBle. I want to connect to a device even though I am not running my application, I don`t mind if any service is running. Moreover if possible when I get close to the device with my phone, it automatically launches the application. What would be the drill for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could register broadcast receiver with specific filter which will wakes up your app when BLE device is available